# Source code compile but NoClassDefFoundError happens on running

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror

So I have multiple projects using Maven and during a full year everything was working but then I tried to implement SymmetricDS and now when I install my "core" projects then try to launch the "main" program it says that it can't find one of my classes from my "core". What could cause this problem? I know I didn't provide any maven file but I don't know which one to show exactly :) If anyone would like to see it to help me just ask and I'll provide it!

edit :
My Structure is the PunchServer using PunchShared using Core
(I've removed custom repo from pom files)

Server pom :
pastebin.com/sfxtXjKb

Shared pom :
pastebin.com/abq7uWrn

Core pom :
pastebin.com/zwZi6R5F

Comment: What is your project structure?

Comment: It could be something like a `provided` dependency that was actually in the environment before and now isn't.  Post your pom.

Comment: updated my structure + added pom files

Comment: have  you tried cleaning up the project/target. Another reason for a class to not load is some compilation error or the class to have been removed from the project source. What Kevin mentioned is reasonable but that would mean whole project or artifact going into air and not be available and not just a particular class in the project.

Comment: Yep I even cleaned up my maven local repo and reinstall everycore project to be sure. I have no compilation error :/

Comment: @OP, PunchServer using PunchShared using Core. Does this mean punchshared is a dependency for server. and in return core is dependency for punchshared

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work now. I only added dependencies to my core...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any details it is rough to guess. But you could check this: Some dependency in your `pom.xml` might be using [a version range](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html) rather than just a fixed version. If a new version of your dependencies was released in these months then your project might be pulling new libraries causing issues you were not having before.

Comment: I've updated my OP but I do not use version range :/

Comment: I have to say my code compile. So I feel like my classpath doesn't add my dependencies to itself..

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError is an error that is thrown when the Java Runtime System tries to load the definition of a class, and that class definition is no longer available. In summary the missing class is not required at compile time but at runtime

Comment: But I don't see why it is not. I've checked the jar from maven it's there

Comment: Sometimes maven gets weird. Try cleaning your maven repository (USER_HOME/.m2/repository). Then run "mvn -U clean install"

Comment: Already tried with no good result.

Comment: Alright I have news. Seems like my problem is dagger-compiler. When I set <optional>true</optional> inside my Core to dagger-compiler I don't have my problem but then my jar file isn't good. If I clear my target folder dagger doesn't seem to compile. So now I know it's a problem with dagger do you know what I should do? Or I should make an other question?